# Superman goes around the world in $2.5$ hrs, and Flash in $1.5$ hrs. How many times will they pass each other going in opposite directions in 24 hrs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Superman and Flash are running around the world in opposite directions. Superman can go around the world in $2.5$ hours, and Flash can do the same in $1.5$ hours. Assuming they start at the same time and place, how many times will they pass each other going in opposite directions in a $24$-hour period?

Superman in 24 hours
$\frac{24}{2.5}=9.6$ laps around the world
Flash in 24 hours
$\frac{24}{1.5}=16$ laps around the world

Superman in an hour
$\frac{9.6}{24}=0.4$ laps around the world
Flash in an hour
$\frac{16}{1.5}=0.\dot{6}$ laps around the world

So in an hour Flash passes Superman at over half of his lap. Their combined lap length is $> 1$.

This much I've understood but couldn't go further myself. However, I found a solution that gave me an answer and partially helped my understanding but I still can't reason why the answer makes sense.

> Let the circumference of the Earth $= C$.
> Every hour Superman covers $\frac{C}{2.5} = \frac{C}{5/2}=\frac{2}{5}C$
> And every hour Falsh covers $\frac{C}{1.5}= \frac{C}{3/2}=\frac{2}{3}C$
> So every hour they cover $(\frac{2}{5} + \frac{2}{3})C = \frac{16}{15}C$
> Which means that it takes them $\frac{15}{16}$ hrs to meet every time.
> So the number of times they meet in $24$ hrs = $\frac{24}{15/16} = 25.6 \approx 25$ times.

The number of times they meet is just the sum of the number of laps both Superman and Flash go around the world in $24$ hrs $16 + 9.6$.

Unfortunately (and embarrassingly), I can't see why. Please help with clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to look at it -

For them to complete one lap together, the time taken is

$t = \displaystyle \frac{2.5 \times 1.5}{4} = 0.9375 \ hr \tag1\ $

To derive $(1)$,

Speed of Flash $s_a = \frac{1}{1.5}$ lap / hr.
Speed of Superman $s_b = \frac{1}{2.5}$ lap / hr.

It is easy to see equation $(1)$ using relative speed. As they are traveling in *opposite* direction, to complete $1$ lap together, it will take them $\displaystyle \frac{1}{s_a + s_b}$ hr.

You can also derive equation $(1)$ as below -

When they meet first time, if Flash has traveled $x$, Superman has traveled $(1-x)$ in the same amount of time $t$.

$\displaystyle t = \frac{x}{s_a} = \frac{1-x}{s_b}$ and you can solve to get equation $(1)$.

Now for them to meet next, they again need to complete one lap together. So  number of times they meet in $24$ hour is given by,

$ \displaystyle n = \lfloor \frac{24}{0.9375} \rfloor = 25$

Comment: Let me know if it is clear. I added some more details.

Comment: This seems to be a harmonic mean problem.

Comment: Sloving $\frac{x}{s_a} = \frac{1-x}{s_b}$ leads to $x = \frac{5}{8}$.

Comment: @Edmund that is correct, same as $2.5/4$. Now $x$ is distance covered by Flash. So if we divide it by speed of flash, we get $t = 2.5 \times 1.5 / 4$ as the time when they meet.

Comment: Ok I see. Getting closer to understanding your formula. So yes $t = \frac{d}{r}. \frac{2.5/4}{1.5} = 5/12$. I don't see how Flash's rate gets in the numerator here $\frac{(2.5)(1.5)}{4}$

Comment: because his speed is $\frac{1}{1.5}$.We wrote $ \displaystyle t = \frac{x}{s_a} = \frac{1-x}{s_b}$. So $t = \frac{x}{s_a}$.

Comment: So denominator is $\frac{1}{1.5}$ and not $1.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Since they run in opposite directions, from Superman's point of view, he's not moving and the Flash is running around the Earth at the speed $(1/2.5 + 1/1.5)$ laps /hr $= 16/15$ laps /hr. Multiplying this by the number of hours means Flash passes him $25.6$ times.

Comment: haha, you have love physicists. I'll remember this answer for when I complete my maths studies and (I'm competent enough to) begin my physics studies.

Comment: Why is it that from Superman's perspective he's not moving and the Flash is running?

Comment: @Edmund In your own perspective, you never move--everything else moves around you.

Answer (score 1):

They meet when their lap length is $1$. Since they start at the same time, let $t$ be the time passed till they meet. So,

$$\frac{\text{Earth}}{2.5 h}t + \frac{\text{Earth}}{1.5 h}t = \text{Earth}$$ Solving this you get

$$\frac {4 \times \text{Earth}}{3.75 h}t = \text{Earth}$$ Solving, you get $t = 0.9375$ and $0.9375$ = $\frac{15}{16}$. Now, just divide $24$ by $\frac{15}{16}$ and you get $\frac{24 \times 16}{15}$ which is roughly $25.6$ and $25.6$ ~ $25$. So they meet $25$ times in an hour